The number of regular elements in a maximal torus is number of the elements of the Weyl group
I'm reading "Representations of Finite and Compact Groups (by Barry Simon)" and struggling with a sentence(p214).
The sentence is

In fact,  for regular classes (those with one and so only regular elements), the number of elements of the class in H is clearly $o(\mathcal{W})$,

Here, $G$ is a semisimple Lie group, $H$ is a maximal torus of $G$, $\mathcal{W}$ is the Weyl group, $o(\mathcal{W})$ is the number of elements of $\mathcal{W}$.
It's not clear for me why the number of regular elements in $H$ is the number of elements of $\mathcal{W}$.
Could you give me a proof or hints?
Thanks.
Sorry, I should written more information. The previous sentences are

The irreducible characters are an orthonormal basis for the set of class functions, that is, functions constant on conjugacy classes. Because all maximal tori are conjugate and exhaust the group, each conjugacy class intersects $H$, so it suffice to know the characters on $H$.

And definition of "regular element" in this book is
$x\in G$ is called regular if and only if $x$ lies in a unique maximal torus.

Unless they are using a different definition of regular than the one I am used to it is not true that $H$ contains a finite number of regular elements (indeed I think the set of regular elements is dense in $H$ - the Lie algebra version certainly is). However I'm not sure that is what the sentence you quote is saying. Rather it seems to be talking about the intersection of some "regular class" with $H$ but without more context I don't know what they mean by that.

I added more information.  I did read again and realized what you said is right. This book tells that the number of elements of the intersection of all classes in $H$ is same to the number of element of the Weyl group. But i still don't understand why the number is same.

What the book says is that if $C$ is a conjugacy class in $G$ whose elements are regular in the sense that you quoted, then $H\cap C$ has as many elements as $W$. It is easy to see that $W$ acts on $H\cap C$ by its natural conjugation action on $H$, and that the action is transitive. Your book then says that the action is free, which is equivalent to saying that if $g\in G$ commutes with a regular element $x\in H$, then $g\in H$. I'm not sure why that is true.

@CaptainLama Wow thanks for teaching and it makes sense!!! I know a normalizer of a regular element is its maximal torus. Thus, the action of $W$ is free!!

Ah yes if that is a known fact then the proof is complete.
